# Crash when running algorithm via PyQGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm, profile

I use a Python plugin which is working great on my computer. But on another one, I get an error at the execution of an algorithm from processing package in PyQGIS:

````
## Report Details
 
**Python Stack Trace**
```
Windows fatal exception: access violation
````

I have some details about the crash :

```
Current thread 0x000030f0 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 72 in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 187 in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108 in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "D:\Users/me/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\myplugin\myscript.py", line 289 in my_function
    result = processing.run('qgis:pointstopath', params)
```

I can't reproduce the error on another computer. Is the problem linked to the user profile ?

Comment: Probably, but try installing `first-aid` and looking at what is happening at `line 289 in my_function of "myplugin\myscript.py",`

Comment: Are you using the same QGIS version on both computers ?

Comment: The "qgis:pointstopath" processing algorithm slightly evolved within QGIS3:

[Pointstopath in QGIS2](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools/pointstopath.html)
VS
[Pointstopath in QGIS3](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path)

Comment: "access violation" could mean that you don't have access to the temporary folder set for QGIS processing or the output folder you choose in the processing dialog form

Comment: @wanderzen yes strictly the same versions.

Comment: @RainForest I tried to reinstall QGIS, delete the default profile then reinstalling the plugin without success. I tried to run the plugin locally. I'm asking myself to fully uninstall QGIS but don't know how to do it ?

Comment: Can you run any other algorithm? What folder is in your TEMP system variable and do you have full access to this folder?